# Is the series convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

the series is $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+...+\dfrac{1}{n})(-1)^n   $

it is not Leibniz series  and it is well known that the series $1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+...+\dfrac{1}{n} $is   disconvergent ! and it is obvious that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+...+\dfrac{1}{n})(-1)^n \not =0$

Comment: if $\sum a_n $ converges then $a_n\rightarrow 0$

Comment: For a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ to converge, it is necessary that $a_n \to 0$. This is not the case here.

Comment: is this not an alternating series, for which you could perform the alternating series test?

Comment: @5xum, it doesn't say that: you *must* add the condition that the convergence to zero is "monotone" (with either $\;a_n<0\;\; \forall\,n\;$ or $\;a_n>0\;\;\;\forall\;n\;$ ...or at least for all indexes but a finite number of them)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Recall that
$$1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1n\sim_\infty\ln n$$

Comment: $1+\frac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+...+\dfrac{1}{n}=\ln{n}+r+\circ(1)  $  and r is the Euler constant!

Answer (score 0):

$S_{2n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n}$

$S_{2n-1}=-1-\frac{-1}{3}\ldots-\frac{1}{2n-1}$.

The first sequence of partial sums diverges to $\infty$ the second one diverges to $-\infty$. Therefore the series is divergent.